# On the sum of two independient normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> Theorem. If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent normal random variables with means $a,b$ and variances $c,d$ respectly, the sum $X+Y$ is a normal random variable with parameters $a+b$ and $c+d$.

My question is, I know that $X$ is normal with parameters $a$ and $c$ if and only if $Z=(X-a)/\surd c$ is standard normal (ie: with parameters $0$ and $1$).   If I show the Theorem above for the case with two standard normal random variables $E$ and $F$ say, can I simply conclude that the result is true for the general case by making:

$X=\frac{(E-a)}{\surd c}$ and $Y=\frac{(F-b)}{\surd d}$ and  $X+Y= \frac{(E+F)-(a+b)}{\surd c+\surd d} $??

Comment: I think $m$ was meant to be $a$? (Also, your question mark key seems to be stuck.)

Comment: Quite apart from independent (no second 'i') normal random variables, that last equation doesn't hold even just for numbers.

Comment: Let me rephrase your statement once more. Suppose $E, F$ are i.i.d. standard normal, and you have shown that $E + F \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$. Then in general, for two independent normally distributed random variables 
$X \stackrel {d} {=} a + \sqrt{c}E \sim \mathcal{N}(a, c)$ and 
$Y \stackrel {d} {=} b + \sqrt{d}F \sim \mathcal{N}(b, d)$, we have
$X + Y \stackrel {d} = a + b + \sqrt{c}E + \sqrt{d}F$ So merely knowing this trick cannot help you to generalize I think.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $E=\frac{X-a}{\surd c}$, $F=\frac{Y-b}{\surd d}$ are independent standard normal random variables, but $E+F$ is distributed $\mathcal N(0,2)$ .

- $a+b + E\surd c+ F\surd d$ is distributed $\mathcal N(a+b, c+d)$
- $E\surd c+F\surd d$ is distributed $\mathcal N(0,c+d)$
- $\frac{E\surd c+F\surd d}{\surd(c+d)}$ is distributed $\mathcal N(0,1)$